# Stuck in "Installation type" section

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, 20.04, boot-partition, nvme

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 on an Asus ROG Strix G512LI. After disabling secure boot and setting to AHCI, I started the install process on a Crucial SSD NVMe M.2. It is now stuck in the Installation type section, sure, it said it would take a long time, but it's been like 3 hours and I have no way of knowing if something's being done, other than the machine not freezing.

[Install section where it's stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtpZa.jpg)

Comment: Can you give us more details What does your screen say?

Comment: Oh sorry @ThomasAichinger, it was such a folly; I first had the drive formatted with gparted, so there was a partition already present. After realizing my mistake, I simply unformatted the drive with gparted and then I had no problem and installation went smoothly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the wait is for you.

This screen is waiting for your input to continue. You must choose a location where to install Ubuntu and then click "Continue".

But it appears that you have no free space.

You should format (erase) your disk before installing Ubuntu.  You can do this in the live session with the Disks application, or you can select the "Erase disk and Install Ubuntu" option prior to this screen.

If you are attempting to dual boot Ubuntu with Windows, you still need to prepare free space for Ubuntu.  If you begin the installer with enough unpartitioned free space, you will be given a guided "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows" option.

Comment: Thanks @Nmath, but I'm  trying to do the install on an empty SSD, because I've had problems with partitioning the disk before, making me lose my Windows partitions.

Comment: It looks like there is already an ext4 partition on the drive, so it is not empty.

Comment: Yes @Nmath, I made it with Gparted. I left it "installing" all night long and there is no progress so far. I read somewhere else about a similar case, and the solution was to install Linux Mint 19.3, I guess that's what I'll try now.