# Ubuntu installer goot stuck at the *Installation type* screen

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

I have an Asus X54UAK with an Intel i3 6th gen CPU. I tried to install Ubuntu using a bootable USB which I created using Balena Etcher.

I got stuck at the *Installation type* screen of the Ubuntu installer for more than two hours. Is this an installation process still going on or did it get stuck? This is the image of the screen at which I got stuck.

[image: This is the image of the screen at which I got stuck]

Comment: Why are you stuck? Do you mean you selected that option then next and nothing heppened?

Comment: did you click "next"?

Comment: The process is going on.   the mouse pointer is circulating   and all option is freezed now

Comment: I have option  at the 5th stage of installation type in which i was asked to erase disk  or something else  and i chosen erase disk then clicked install now  and mouse pointer  start  rotating in circular motion  shows like process is going   and all options  got freeze but at right upper notch  the battery percentage  and brightness ,wifi control is working but when i go to installing screen it all freezes. And this is happening for more than 2 hours.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stuck in "Installation type" section](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1297084/stuck-in-installation-type-section)

Answer (score 0):

Filling a disk with random data can take a long time.  It will depend on the speed of the machine, method of generating randomness, and the size of the drive.

1TB drive, writing only zeros or ones, at 100MB/s can take about three hours.  Sometimes you cannot generate that much random data, so 100MB/s would be faster than you could actually write data.  That also assumes 100MB/s is the fastest you can write to your drive.

You should be seeing a progress bar, or another screen, after saying you want to zero out your drive.  The progress should increase over time, showing you it hasn't frozen.  Are you not getting to this screen and you're stuck on the screen you showed?  You want to make sure you hit "Next" on the screen you showed.

Comment: I have option at the 5th stage of installation type in which i was asked to erase disk or something else and i chosen erase disk then clicked install now and mouse pointer start rotating in circular motion shows like process is going and all options got freeze but at right upper notch the battery percentage and brightness ,wifi control is working but when i go to installing screen it all freezes. And this is happening for more than 2 hours.

Comment: I dont see any progress  bar and clicked  next  but after it ,it got frozen and its going to be more than 2 hours  it remains frozen.